# PHP to MySql - Will only write one column, not multiple

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm new to php and am having some trouble with inserting data across multiple columns.

This is my php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    mysql_query("Insert into rooms (Room,DateofEvent)
    Values('".$_REQUEST['room']."' AND '".$_REQUEST['DateofEvent']."')");
 ?>
```

It's taking the result from android with this code

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("room","Boole 1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DateofEvent","2011-01-01"));
    try{
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/databasewrite.php");
         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();
       }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
       }
   }
```

As it is,I think the problem might be in php. It works when I have it as only one column on the insert, but as soon as put in the comma, it doesn't

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: **WARNING** your code is very suseptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: I know, this is just for a prototype demo, and is hosted locally, actual web service is set up and safer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("Insert into rooms (Room,DateofEvent)
    Values('".$_REQUEST['room']."' , '".$_REQUEST['DateofEvent']."')");
```

try like this ? Separate the Value using "," not "AND"

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
mysql_query("Insert into rooms (Room,DateofEvent)
Values('".$_REQUEST['room']."' AND '".$_REQUEST['DateofEvent']."')");
```

to this:

```
mysql_query("Insert into rooms (Room,DateofEvent)
Values('".$_REQUEST['room'].",".$_REQUEST['DateofEvent']."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
mysql_query("Insert into rooms (Room,DateofEvent)
    Values('".$_REQUEST['room']."' AND '".$_REQUEST['DateofEvent']."')");
```

should probably be

```
mysql_query("Insert into rooms (Room,DateofEvent)
    Values('".$_REQUEST['room']."' , '".$_REQUEST['DateofEvent']."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't join the values in the `VALUES` clause with `AND`. Use a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `AND` to separate your columns, use a comma(`,`).

also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Read somewhat more on the [INSERT-syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), because it's quite a basic mistake you're making. Replace the `AND` work by a `,` and it will work.

By the way, please also read a good article on SQL injection. You have to escape input from the user that you are using in a query or anyone can delete, read and modify your entire database!

Just [Google on SQLInjection](http://www.google.nl/search?q=sqlinjection) and see [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for more info!